# Separating an array of strings to create a table row

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making an API call and retrieving JSON in the following format:

```
"1": ["building 1 name","building 1 floor","building 1 room"],
"2": ["building 2 name","building 2 floor","building 2 room"],
"n": ["building n name","building n floor","building n room"]
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is render all of this data in a table, where each row of the table is made up of items in the array, like this:

```
<tr>
<td>building 1 name</td><td>building 1 floor</td><td>building 1 room</td>
</tr>
```

But, I'm having a far harder time than I thought I would.

I guess I know I need to iterate over the arrays and pull out the values for each item, something like:

```
const data = APIResponse;
for(let i in data) {
    // Do something here to get each value out
}
```

But, and it's embarrassing to admit...I'm stuck. I'm trying to teach myself as I go but I'm sure this is a fundamental thing I should really know.

Comment: This might help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: What does the HTML you are trying to insert this into look like? Generally in your loop you will make the nodes and add them to the existing document. The better way to do this is with some type of data binding framework.

Comment: @MattBurland - It's just a basic HTML table, I want each string in the array to sit within its own <td> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done, that `i` variable holds the current key, so all you need to do more is to iterate over each array and generate HTML, maybe like this:

```js
const data = {
    "1": ["building 1 name","building 1 floor","building 1 room"],
    "2": ["building 2 name","building 2 floor","building 2 room"],
    "n": ["building n name","building n floor","building n room"]
}

var html = "";
for(let key in data) {
    html += `<tr>`;
    for(let idx in data[key]) {
        html += `<td>${data[key][idx]}</td>`;
    }
    html += `</tr>`;
}
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<table id="table">

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's correct answer, please mark it as correct so anyone who will want to ask same question will know what was the right :)

Comment: Thanks @Dominik, it worked like a charm. Thank you for having patience with me!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Dominik, could you help me a bit further? How would I output only the rows that contained a specific string, so referring back to your example, how would I filter the results to only display rows containing "building 1 name"?

Comment: if you have exact string then you can do in `for` loop this -> `if(!data[key].contains(yourString)) continue;`

Comment: Thanks again Dominik, that worked great. One thing I've noticed is that a <tr></tr> element is printed for each key, not just the ones containing the string I want to isolate. I guess that's because it's outside the if?

Comment: You need to put that if statement before `html += `<tr>`

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

with `Array.prototype.map` & `Object.entries`

```js
const data = {
"1": ["building 1 name","building 1 floor","building 1 room"],
"2": ["building 2 name","building 2 floor","building 2 room"],
"n": ["building n name","building n floor","building n room"]
}
const output = Object.entries(data).reduce((out, [, row]) => [
   ...out,
   '<tr>',
   ...row.map(col => `<td>${col}</td>`),
   '</tr>'
], []).join('');

document.querySelector('table').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<table border="1">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/rso97uae/

```
var data = {"1": ["building 1 name","building 1 floor","building 1 room"],
            "2": ["building 2 name","building 2 floor","building 2 room"],
            "n": ["building n name","building n floor","building n room"]}

for(let i in data) {
    const obj = data[i];
    console.log(obj);
    const name = obj[0];
    const floor = obj[1];
    const room = obj[2];

    // render each here, with name, floor and room
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like I did below. See the comments for more explanation:

```js
const data = {
  "1": ["building 1 name", "building 1 floor", "building 1 room"],
  "2": ["building 2 name", "building 2 floor", "building 2 room"],
  "n": ["building n name", "building n floor", "building n room"]
}

//Start with a new document fragment and use DOM API to append required nodes
const frag = Object.entries(data).reduce((accum, entry) => {
  const [key, val] = entry;
  const trEl = document.createElement('tr');
  val.forEach(el => {
    const tdEl = document.createElement('td');
    tdEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(el));
    trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
  });
  accum.appendChild(trEl);
  return accum;
}, document.createDocumentFragment());

//Append the entire fragment to the table
document.querySelector('table').appendChild(frag)
```

```html
<table border="1"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You i variable contains the key of the response object. So you just need to retrieve the value and render them into a row.  Something like the following should work.

```js
const data = {
        "1": ["building 1 name","building 1 floor","building 1 room"],
        "2": ["building 2 name","building 2 floor","building 2 room"],
        "n": ["building n name","building n floor","building n room"]
    };


    let output = document.getElementById('output'),
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


    for(let key in data) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');

        for(let cellData of data[key]) {
            let cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        fragment.appendChild(row);
    }


    output.appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<table id="output"></table>
```